# Directory.GetDirectories with applied ExcusionsList with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, directoryinfo

I have:

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

Decided to exclude some folders which they were listed in an array:

```
string[] ExcludingList;
```

And trying to achieve it via LINQ:
So was trying something similar to the line below, but yet the format is wrong:

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
    .Where(d => (! ExcludingList.Contains(d.Name)));
```

I know it is still wrong, maybe an extra initialization, a type change, conversion, or changing a bit of format be needed, can you help me with it?

Comment: what about using `Except()`? `var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Except(ExcludingList);`

Comment: Nice, guess it is even better.

Comment: @HadiRj feel free to add your answer, you will get at least +1 from me, about changing it as the answer I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is good, but the issue is `d` represent the `Name` of sub directory, then you don't need to use `d.Name`, use just `d`, change little the code to :

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
    .Where(d => !ExcludingList.Contains(d))
    .ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Don't know why still it didn't work for me, need to play more with it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments you may use [Except()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?) to achieve what you are looking for.

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Except(ExcludingList);
```

Comment: A question, can we apply items with wildcards in the ExcludingList? for example "**\\obj" ?

Comment: @Kasrak then you may use some method like [String.EndsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=netcore-3.1), I guess.